What are some examples of image manipulation outside of photography context?
The What topics can I ask about here? page says that "Image Manipulation (outside of the Photography context)" is off-topic here. But it doesn't give examples on what is inside and outside of photography context. Can you give some?

Do you have a specific example question or context in mind?

I would have two criteria for image-manipulation here on PSE:

The image is a photo
You are not adding any foreign elements (removal is OK for aesthetic purposes).

If any of these are not met, the question is better asked on GDSE.

Why is removing elements out ok but adding them in not? Can you give some examples on what count as aesthetic purpose and what don't?

Because when you add elements you are composing your own image, even it uses photos. For removal, cropping/reframing the picture, or removing tourists or a loose plastic bag in a landscape serves an aesthetic purpose, removing someone from a group picture is not.

Generally, non-photographic image manipulation (i.e., graphics) is off-topic here.
"Inside of a photographic context" is things like: photo retouching; color balancing; image stacking.
See the image-manipulation tag for questions tagged "image-manipulation".
